# query and display multiple columns from android sqlitedatabase

Tags: android

```
public class AbidingInChrist {

public Cursor queryPromises() {

    Cursor wrapped = getReadableDatabase().PromiseHelper.query(PromiseHelper.db, "SELECT * FROM promises WHERE Category = "Abiding In Christ", null, null, ORDER BY Book ASC");
    Return new Cursor(wrapped);
 }
```

I'm trying to query the database for this specific category and output it to the following xml layout:

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCategory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Category"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Book"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSpace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtChapter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chapter"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtColon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=":"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVerse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Verse"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtWord"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Word"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

I've looked at many examples and am not sure of the proper way to go about it.  I've tried a few things, but they haven't worked.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please tell us what the problem is, a bit more specifically? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how to set the results to the various textboxes.  Plus the code isn't working for the query to get the result to the cursor.

Comment: Ok - I think my answer addresses those questions. Not 100% how you want the information to be laid out in xml though so the answer might not be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want

```
return dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM promises ORDER BY book ASC", null);
```

for the queryPromises() method.

Then to use the Cursor elsewhere:

```
TextView book = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBook);
Cursor c = queryPromises();
c.moveToFirst(); //or c.moveToPosition(recordNoInDatabase)
book.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("columnNameForBook")));
```

Then do all the other `TextView`s. Not sure if the setting text is correct because I'm not sure where you want the text.

Comment: That's great but it's not taking the setContentView or the findViewById statements.

Comment: If you're not using setContentView, then what is the purpose of your xml layout?

Comment: No problem, if my answer was what you were looking for then please accept/upvote it

Comment: So that's how it works.  I'm only a 6, says got to be a 15 to vote, but I sure did star it!  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok no worries, it helps other people find the answers to their similar problems quicker because the question will be marked as answered

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I guess you can tell I'm new.  I just posted another question about the manifest file and strings and such if you have time to look it up.